# Why do I need CA cert file to make SSL connection to the server from Java?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, pem

I have a self-signed client certificate in PEM format to make connection with a server via SSL Socket. This certificate looks like the following:

**client.pem**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In Python my client code needs only this PEM file and works well:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)
context.load_cert_chain('client.pem', password='password')
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = context.wrap_socket(sock)
sock.connect(('localhost', 2007))
...
```

I had to translate this code to Java. I wrote working code by using Not-Yet-Commons-SSL library, but it turned out I also need the CA.crt. Without it this code doesn't work at all.

```
SSLClient client = new SSLClient();
client.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "SSLv3" });
client.addTrustMaterial( TrustMaterial.DEFAULT );
client.addTrustMaterial( new TrustMaterial( "CA.crt" ) );
client.setKeyMaterial( new KeyMaterial( "client.pem", "password".toCharArray() ) );
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) client.createSocket("localhost", 2007);
...
```

Why does Java need this CA certificate, while Python doesn't need it? How can I get rid of this one in Java?

Comment: KeyMaterial probably ignores the CA certificates embedded in the PEM file.